# Make all ticks appear on axis using R plotly

Tags: r, graph, plotly, r-plotly

I wrote a code to make a subplots with scatterplots using my data. Here is a graph:

[image]

This is hours on x axis. As you see, not all of them appear on x axis. How could i make all 24 hours be on axis? Even if for example in dataframe there is no value for 23 o'clock, i want it to be on x axis. How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
plot <- function(df) {

  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        name = ~ paste(metrics, " - ", time_pos),
        colors = ~ time_pos,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines+markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 7,
          color = "white",
          line = list(width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 700,
        height = 620
      ) %>% layout(autosize = T,legend = list(font = list(size = 8)))
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.05)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved in `layout` via the attribute `xaxis` like so. The ticks or breaks can be set via `tickvals`, the tick labels via `ticktext`.

This is illustrasted using some random data in the reproducible example below:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(42)

d <- data.frame(
  x = sort(sample(24, 15)),
  y = 1:15 + runif(15),
  z = 1:15 + runif(15)
)

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~z, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickvals = 1:24, ticktext = paste0(1:24, "h")))
```

[image]